# docker containers stops while creating staging environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am deploying, on 3 different environments (test, stage & production) an API.
I am used to deploy with docker-compose so I wrote 2 services (1 for my API and 1 for a database) like following:

```
# file docker-compose.yml

version: '3.3'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my_api:${TAG}
    ports:
      - "${API_PORT_FROM_ENV}:8000"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: whatever:v0.0.0
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT_FROM_ENV}:5000"
    env_file:
      - .env
```

In the file above, you can find the **parent services**.
Thne, I wrote 2 files that explains my strategy to deploy **on the same Virtual Machine** my containers:

-> staging environment below

```
# docker-compose.stage.yml
version: "3.3

services: 
  api:
    container_name: api_stage
  environment:
    - environment="staging"

  db:
    container_name: db_stage
  environment:
    - environment="staging"
  volumes:
    - /I/Mount/a/local/volume/stage:/container/volume
```

-> production environment below

```
# docker-compose.prod.yml
version: "3.3

services: 
  api:
    container_name: api_prod
  environment:
    - environment="production"

  db:
    container_name: db_prod
  environment:
    - environment="production"
  volumes:
    - /I/Mount/a/local/volume/prod:/container/volume
```

**My problem**:

The production is actually running.
I deploy my containers with the following command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build
```

I want to deploy a *staging* environment on the same virtual machine. I want **my api_prod + db_prod running in parallel with api_stage + db_stage**.

Unfortunatly, when I run the command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.stage.yml up --build
```

My containers called api_prod and db_prod stops. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I **need to specify --project-name option** that allows me to run both containers from stage and production environment without concurrency.

Below the 2 commands:

```
# Stage
docker-compose --project-name stage -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build

# Production
docker-compose --project-name prod -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build
```

I am also open to other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify different port bindings as well:

```yaml
# docker-compose.stage.yml
version: "3.3

services: 
  api:
    container_name: api_stage
    ports:
        - "8001:8000"
  environment:
    - environment="staging"

  db:
    container_name: db_stage
    ports:
        - "xxxY:xxxx"
  environment:
    - environment="staging"
  volumes:
    - /I/Mount/a/local/volume/stage:/container/volume
```

Comment: I have edited my post. I am actually changing my port on staging and production based on envionment variables coming from .env file

Comment: are you running docker-compose with `-d` flag?

Comment: I tried both, with or without and it is not working